superscript on the left
How to write ^*R correctly in LaTex so that the * is closer to R?
As you can see in the picture, the * is very far from the R.
Thank you.

Edit Here is the code

\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{amsbook}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{txfonts}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{mathdots}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{verbatim,enumitem}


\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Remark}
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\@thm
{\let\thm@indent\indent}{\let\thm@indent\noindent}%
{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    
    \title{Result}
    
    \begin{definition}\label{linear_representation}
        \leavevmode\begin{enumerate}[label=\roman*), font=\normalfont]
            \item $ ^*R_{L}^G $.
            
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{definition}

\end{document}


Does leftindex (suggested in the link above) work? It supports kerning of left scripts.

I tried leftindex, but it produces exactly the same result as in the screenshot, It seems so far away from R. Thank you.

Then please show us the short compilable TeX code you have tried so far! Then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

@Mensch Please find the minimal working example in the edited question. Thank you.

The idea is to use (note {} before ^ or you could get bad surprises).
{}^{*\mkern-3mu}R

but as this kern isn't good for other letters, I suggest a command that looks for the letter to be prescripted and use a suitable kern. The default will be -3mu, but you can specify exceptions for other letters as shown below.
I made two important changes to your code:

txfonts provides really badly spaced fonts, so I replaced it with newtx;

hyperref should go last.


Experiment with the kerns, below my attempt. Don't worry if you don't understand the code for showing the full list. It should be easy to see how a specific kern is added for a particular letter in the definition of \conj_prestar_kern:n.
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{amsbook}

%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}% not needed
%\usepackage{txfonts}% bad fonts
\usepackage{newtx}% better Times based fonts
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{mathdots}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{verbatim,enumitem}
\usepackage{hyperref}% should be last


\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Remark}
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}

\theoremstyle{definition}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@thm}{\let\thm@indent\indent}{\let\thm@indent\noindent}{}{}
\makeatother

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\prestar}{m}
 {
  {}^{*\mkern-\conj_prestar_kern:n {#1}mu} #1
 }
\cs_new:Nn \conj_prestar_kern:n
 {
  \str_case:nnF { #1 }
   {
    {A}{5}
    {C}{2}
    {G}{2}
    {J}{4}
    {O}{2}
    {Q}{2}
    {T}{1}
    {U}{2}
    {V}{1}
    {W}{1}
    {Y}{0}
    {Z}{2}
   }
   {3}% default
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{definition}\label{linear_representation}
\leavevmode
\begin{enumerate}[label=\roman*), font=\normalfont]
  \item $\prestar{R}_{L}^G $.
  \item $\prestar{A}+\prestar{B}+\prestar{C}$
\end{enumerate}
\end{definition}

\noindent
Full list:
\ExplSyntaxOn
\parbox[t]{0.5\textwidth}{\raggedright
  \tl_map_inline:nn {ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}{$\prestar{#1}$\space}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}



You could add a thin negative space after the asterisk.  Here are both versions shown together:
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{amsbook}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{txfonts}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{mathdots}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{verbatim,enumitem}


\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Remark}
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\@thm
{\let\thm@indent\indent}{\let\thm@indent\noindent}%
{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    
    \title{Result}
    
    \begin{definition}\label{linear_representation}
        \leavevmode\begin{enumerate}[label=\roman*), font=\normalfont]
            \item $ ^*R_{L}^G $.
            \item $ ^*\!R_{L}^G $.
            
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{definition}

\end{document}


and here is the result:

